# Regular Expression issue in C# returning match true

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is the regular expression i have written and it returns true if `"$"` or `"^"` is passed.Why does it return true when i specified only the below characters should match

```
public static bool IsTrue(string test)
{
    Regex regex =  new Regex(@"(([a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z+\\-\\.]*:)?/{0,2}[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$\\.\\-_!~*'()%]+)?(#[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$\\.\\-_!~*'()%]+)?");    
    return regex.IsMatch(test);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't accidentally written a Perl program? But seriously, it's so complex there's probably an error **somewhere**.

Comment: You should supply us with some sample data for the regex.

Comment: I tried inputting string test="abc$$^^".Since abc matches that is ok but there is no where in regex to match $ sign and ^ sign.so it should return false for the whole string

Comment: That is very little to go on. Provide examples of what is acceptable, what should be rejected, etc., we shouldn't have to make up these samples.

Comment: Only extended alpha numeric characters should be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all parts of your regex are optional, that means that even an *empty* string will match your regex. Even if some invalid string were passed in, it would still match a zero-length substring at the start of the input.

Also, you've escaped the slashes. This is not necessary in a verbatim string literal (a string literal starting with `@`). The string regular string literal `"foo\\bar"` is equivalent to to the verbatim literal `@"foo\bar"` .

I think you'll want to add start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors to your pattern:

```
new Regex(@"^(([a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z+\-.]*:)?/{0,2}[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$.\-_!~*'()%]+)?(#[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$.\-_!~*'()%]+)?$");
```

This will make `^` fail, but an empty string still matches (since all parts are still optional) and `$` is still valid input. It's hard to tell exactly how to modify this pattern without more information on what you want to match and what you don't want to match.

According to your comments, if you simply want to restrict input to a few characters, you can simply use the pattern:

```
new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9 '()&#/\\+;:-]*$");
```

Comment: I was looking only for extended alphanumeric characters to be matched.

Comment: @suryabhai You'll have to be more clear. What do you mean by "*extended alphanumeric characters*"? If you're just looking at matching a single set of characters why not just use one character class?

Comment: extended alphanumeric characters mean  the 74 characters A-Z (capital A through capital Z), a-z (lower case a through lower case z), 0-9 (zero through nine), the space, ' (single quotation or apostrophe), () (left and right parenthesis), & (ampersand), # (pound or hash sign), / (forward slash), \ (backslash), + (plus sign), ; (semi-colon), : (colon) and - (dash or hyphen).

Comment: @suryabhai I've updated my answer with a pattern that matches what you've specified.

Comment: @suryabhai - the last response by p.s.w.g. meets your needs based on your comments, but just curious what the intent was with the separate groups?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your match, every group ends with a ? making all parts optional:

```
(
    (
        [a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z+\\-\\.]*:
    )?
    /{0,2}[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$\\.\\-_!~*'()%]+
)?
(
    #[0-9a-zA-Z;/?:@&=+$\\.\\-_!~*'()%]+
)?
```

I had to reformat as above to confirm it.